# Why is aapt not adding `<values/>` in the apk?

Tags: android, titanium

I am using Titanium which is a cross-platform development Tool. Titanium uses it own building script to create the apk.

I have a Titanium application that uses a native module : a Java library that makes VOIP calls. The Java application works, and when I create a Titanium application with an empty module, it works.

But I have a **build problem** using a module based on the VOIP module inside the Titanium application : **some Resources are missing in the apk.**

First the build system merges some Resources from our Titanium application and some native android modules and put them in a directory `build`. I have for exemple : `build/android/res/values/strings.xml` file **where all keys and values seems ok and valid xml**.

Then the build calls aapt and create the apk using also the Titanium Resources for library widgets (ex: strings for notifications). And in this apk, the `build/android/res/values/strings.xml` is missing. It doesn't exists. The application starts, the VOIP service starts, and then it's crashes as soon that a required missing Resource is called.

[image: Titanium build]

I can prove with `aapt list` or unzipping the apk that `strings.xml` is missing.

Looking deep in the titanium javascript build file, I see this command is executed :

```
aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "/Users/nicorama/ti-voip/build/android/gen" 
"-M" "/Users/nicorama/ti-voip/project/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" 
"-S" "/project/build/android/res"
"-S" "/var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res"
"-S" "/var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res" ....
```

The `/var/folders/...` are files for Titanium widgets. Compilation of the apk fails if I remove them.
I have executed this command outside the build, adding `-v` for verbose mode and saving result into a `log.txt`. I'm searching in this file for *strings.xml* and I find :

```
Found 18 custom asset files in /Users/nicorama/ti-voip/build/android/bin/assets
Configurations:
 (default)
 v11
 v14
 ....
 Src: () /var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res/values/ids.xml
  values/strings.xml
    Src: () /var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res/values/strings.xml
    Src: (af) /var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res/values-af/strings.xml
    Src: (am) /var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res/values-am/strings.xml
...
```

But nothing about my `/Users/nicorama/ti-voip/build/android/res/values/strings.xml` folder which is first in the appt command.

I do have all references needed for images or other xml files thought :

```
(new resource id hidden from /Users/nicorama/ti-voip/build/android/res/layout/hidden.xml)
(new resource id launcher from /Users/nicorama/ti-voip/build/android/res/layout/launcher.xml)
```

Any idea where and why this strings.xml has disappeared ?

Comment: updated my answer, were you able to test it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

aapt will merge all strings.xml "values" into resources.arsc, which is why you do not see the file `strings.xml` in the apk. I double checked this with few of my apks, i do not see the strings.xml inside the apk.

If you would like to see the string values that were packaged with your 'apk', run the below command it will dump all string values.

```
    aapt.exe d strings myapp.apk
```

Verify some of the string values you defined in your app, are listed in the above string dump. If not, try passing in absolute path to the "res" folder **`"/Users/nicorama/ti-voip/project/build/android/res"`** at the beginning:

```
    aapt "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "/Users/nicorama/ti-voip/build/android/gen" 
    "-M" "/Users/nicorama/ti-voip/project/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml" 
    "-S" "/Users/nicorama/ti-voip/project/build/android/res"
    "-S" "/var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res"
    "-S" "/var/folders/6f/twxz46614h7_q/res" ....
```

the new apk should have the xml values, test again with

```
    aapt.exe d strings myapp.apk
```

to make sure your strings.xml values are in the above string dump.

Comment: Hi, I had to change the path because there is the name of the client, forgetting the 'android' inside. Unfortunately, it's not the good answer.

Comment: I do have my strings, so the problem is somewhere else :)